# Trello API Authentication -- Node with OAuth -- Getting the oauth_verifier for Service

Tags: api, node.js, oauth, trello

maybe I am not understanding the OAuth flow correctly, but this is what I want to be able to do: I have a service that will issue request to Trello's API, so, in order to perform some of the requests, I need to have a access token.

Is this even possible? I know that you can do this with other services, like Twitter, but I don't know if I can do this against Trello.

I am using NodeJS with a library called [oauth](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth) to do this, and my flow looks like this: I created a new OAuth object, call **getOAuthRequestToken** and then I call **getOAuthAccessToken** in the callback, and is there where I get an 500 error saying that the **oauth_verifier** is missing.

Here the piece of code I am talking about:

```
var OAuth = require('oauth').OAuth,
    oauth = new OAuth('https://trello.com/1/OAuthGetRequestToken?key=' + config.key,
                      'https://trello.com/1/OAuthGetAccessToken',
                      config.key,
                      config.secret,
                      '1.0',
                      null,
                      'PLAINTEXT');

    oauth.getOAuthRequestToken(function(error, oauth_token, oauth_secret, results){
          //Here I have some error handling code
          oauth.getOAuthAccessToken(oauth_token, oauth_secret,
                function(error, oauth_access_token, oauth_access_token_secret, access_results){
                //Here I would be storing the access token for later, etc.
                }
    });
```

So, obviously, I am not passing the **oauth_verifier** parameter to the **getOAuthAccessToken** method (I checked in the code and that function is expecting the verifier as third parameter), but I am not doing it because I do not have it: the **results** object is empty and I do not know how to get it programmatically.

Another thing to notice is that I am passing the **key** parameter in the **request token url** and using **plaintext** as signature because I just thought that would be the right thing to do (I haven't see any reference in the documentation about what kind of signature to use or if I need to pass the key as a parameter).

Am I doing things really wrong? Am I in the correct track? what am I missing?

As always, thanks in advance! =)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I’m looking into improving the node-trello API wrapper to include OAuth support, and am stuck at the same point. :)

Comment: I'm stuck at the same point as well - any updates on this one?

Comment: stuck at the same point, trello documenttion for API auth is very sparse

Answer (score 0):

[Trello docs](https://trello.com/docs/) don't say much about oAuth.

I'd speculate that the issue would be that Trello is oAuth 2.0 (used by Facebook, Google) and you're using the oAuth 1.0 scheme (used by Twitter, Tumblr).

For what it's worth, the node-oauth library has an oAuth2 implementation in its `lib` directory you can include via `require` in node.js.

Comment: roger that, thanks for the comments. I'll try that and see if that works =)

Comment: Here's an example of oAuth2 usage: https://github.com/ciaranj/connect-auth/blob/master/lib/auth.strategies/facebook.js

Comment: No, Trello doesn't use OAuth 2.0. Its document refers to RFC 5849, which is OAuth 1.0. See https://trello.com/docs/gettingstarted/index.html#getting-a-token-from-a-user